# SELECT statement with spaces between tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT pvov.id, pvov.value
FROM ci_product_variant_option_values pvov, ci_product_variant_options pvo
WHERE pvov.product_variant_option_id=pvo.id
AND pvo.product_id='12345'
```

Now, what I don't understand is what should  `ci_product_variant_option_values pvov` mean, as it has neither any commas or dots. I know that `ci_product_variant_option_values` is a table in the database, however `pvov` (probably an abreviation for product variant option values) has no occurrence in the db.

Can someone please explain me the statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pvov` is the table alias.

Same as saying:

```
ci_product_variant_option_values AS pvov
```

Aliases make code cleaner, instead of having to use `ci_product_variant_option_values.id` you can simply use `pvov.id`

I'd also suggest moving away from the deprecated syntax by using explicit `JOIN` criteria:

```
SELECT pvov.id, pvov.value  
FROM ci_product_variant_option_values pvov
JOIN ci_product_variant_options pvo
ON pvov.product_variant_option_id=pvo.id 
WHERE ....
```

Comment: It's just old code I need to refactor :) I already started modifying stuff and using the JOIN word. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`pvov` is an alias for `ci_product_variant_option_values`.